# How can I capture a result from <<EOF and put into a variable in bash?

Tags: sql, linux, bash, oracle, shell

I need create a linux script and in this script I need capture the result of the SQL query in Oracle using `<<EOF` and put into a variable for example:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
conn c##myuser/mypassowd
col product for a20
select product from myuser.table where id = 10;
EOF
```

What I need is put the result of SQL query into a bash variable, how can I do it?

Comment: `OEF` != `EOF` (and the answer is: use backtics)

Comment: Thanks, I get to correct!

Comment: Also `<` != `<<` but the answer is NOT "use backticks" - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Rather than trying to capture the output in a shell variable I suggest you SPOOL the output to a file, then use a read loop to process the lines in the file.

Comment: @BobJarvis see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219

Comment: @EdMorton Backticks do work,even around a here-document invoked command.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, they do for the most part but see the article I referenced for why not to use them even so.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm afraid you are right. it would need (at least) a sub-shell.

Comment: After all, it did work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) for your commands, then redirect the output to some file.

Something like this:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog > myfile.txt <<EOF
conn c##myuser/mypassowd
col product for a20
select product from myuser.table where id = 10;
EOF
```

I don't have sqlplus handy to test it myself, but the above should be "close"...

This should be able to put it into a variable:

```
myvar=$(sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
  conn c##myuser/mypassowd
  col product for a20
  select product from myuser.table where id = 10;
EOF
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the initial spaces (or use a tab and <<- instead)? And the manual suggests that the ending EOF should be alone on the line.

Comment: Thanks, the first option don't worked here for redirect the output to some file but the second option worked for me, if possible edit the first option!

Comment: @Danilo Neto - you're correct.  The "EOF" (the "here document delimiter") should go on a line by itself.  That means that the redirect ( "... > myfile.txt") should go *BEFORE* the "<<EOF".  My bad:(  I updated the post.  Please "accept" the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[this is for Postgres,but the shell-syntax is the same]

---

```
#/bin/sh
DB=twitters
DB_USER=postgres

count=`psql -qtA -U ${DB_USER} ${DB} <<OEF
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tweeps;
OEF`

echo "Count=${count}"

#eof
```

---

Output:

---

```
Count=14458
```